# btrfs filesystem resize doesn't do anything

Tags: btrfs

I'm trying to increase the size of `/home`.

First I extended the LV via:

```
sudo lvextend --size +1024M /dev/vg_svelte/home
```

Then I did:

```
$ sudo btrfs filesystem resize max /home
Resize '/home' of 'max'
```

Minutes later, nothing has happened, I see:

```
$ btrfs fil show home
Label: 'home'  uuid: 93722fa7-7e8f-418a-a7ca-080aca8db94b
        Total devices 1 FS bytes used 179.03GiB
        devid    1 size 201.00GiB used 200.00GiB path /dev/mapper/vg_svelte-home
```

The total - used == 1GB.

How do I get btrfs to use the 1GB that I just allocated to its LV?

Comment: Anything in the output of `dmesg` after running the `resize` command (again)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really isn't an answer, but I tried again to get the `dmesg` output requested, and it worked this time.

I searched back in time and had multiple lines like:

```
BTRFS info (device dm-2): new size for /dev/mapper/vg_svelte-home is 215817912320
```

But there was never an error message.

Perhaps btrfs needs a `status` command for showing a resize in progress, or there was a gremlin in the system.